# Unable to access the PUT API service of Magento 2 through Python

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, database, api

I'm trying to update a particular product in Magento through `PUT` using python. I'm using `OAuth1Service` for authentication to Magento 2. `GET` products is actually giving me all the products in Magento where as `PUT` payload is not taking payload.

My payload is a JSON string

```
'''{
   "product": {
   "price": 1,
   "extension_attributes": {
   "stock_item": {"qty": 2}
   }
  }
}'''
```

My put request looks like this, the headers has the authentication token and the content type inside it.

```
payload = json.loads(product)
r = session.put(
'products/12345',
headers=headers,
data=json.dumps(payload),
)
```

Rather than taking the payload, it is giving me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is trying to load the product by SKU but you didn't send it in your Json. Even though you are passing the SKU on your URL, SKU is still a required field. , try with:

```
{
  "product": {
  "price": 1,
  "sku": 12345,
  "extension_attributes": {
  "stock_item": {"qty": 2}
  }
 }
}
```

Here in swagger is showing that SKU is required. Follow swagger for your next requests.

[image: Swagger tutorial]